# Center alignment within a Frame

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I would like to know how I can horizontally align to center textboxes and labels inside a Frame in VBA. Basically, I want each text box to be placed at the center of the Frame with the corresponding label next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to gather :

1. `UserForm.Width` (same for all "rows")
2. `TextBox.Width` (different for each TextBox)
3. `Label.Width` (different for each Label)

And then :

```
Label.Left = (UserForm.Width - TextBox.Width - Label.Width) / 2
TextBox.Left = (UserForm.Width - TextBox.Width - Label.Width) / 2 + Label.Width
```

Comment: This actually places the elements at the center of the UserForm, but the method to place them a the center of a Frame is similar, thanks.

Comment: Yup sorry, I forgot the frame while I was typing, but indeed it is the same principle! Enjoy